# PHP: How can exif_imagetype() function accept JPG files (instead of JPEG ones)?

Tags: php, image

I'm using the PHP [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) function, and trying to accept these types of images:

IMAGETYPE_PNG

IMAGETYPE_**JPEG**

IMAGETYPE_GIF

But there's no IMAGETYPE_**JPG** imagetype constant, so all .jpg files are not accepted. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMAGETYPE_JPEG` works for files with extensions jpg and jpeg :

```
var_dump(exif_imagetype ( "abc.jpg" ) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
var_dump(exif_imagetype ( "abc.jpeg" ) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
```

outputs

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `.jpeg` and `.jpg` files. You do not need to treat them separately.

JPG is an abbreviation for JPEG, originally only used on DOS systems which did not support filename extensions longer than three characters.